"Ghost" Maven dependency cannot be deleted
I have a dependency in my Maven project which I cannot get go away, it is making it impossible to build my project.
My Maven dependencies look like this:Screenshot of Maven dependencies from IntelliJ
The one I want to go away is the "java_cup:java-cup:unknown (system)"
It does not exist in my pom.xml, and whenever I try to reload the project I am met with the following error:
'Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\Program Files\javaCUP\java-cup-11b.jar"'
Which after searching thoroughly, is not a section of text that exists anywhere in my project, and does not exist in the "effective POM" either, it does not tell me exactly where this error occurred.
I cannot get this dependency to go away, I believe it is what is causing the error when reloading my project. This is an issue exclusive to my local machine, cloning the GitHub repo with the maven project does not replicate the error.
Any help is appreciated...
I have tried the following:
Clearing IntelliJ cache
Clearing Maven cache both with "remove-project-artifact" and "purge-local-repository"
Deleting all libraries in my project
Deleting the target folder
Deleting files from the Users/user/.m2 folder
mvn clean install - which fails because I am unable to make Maven install new libraries, because I cannot reload my project.
For some reason, running the project using mvn clean javafx:run works fine, but I cannot run it in any other way, I cannot build it, or reload the project.
pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>21-ea+24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>21-ea+24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jhoenicke</groupId>
        <artifactId>jh-javacup</artifactId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


That error might be coming from a former javaCUP project

"It does not exist in my pom.xml" Show, don't tell. You can try closing intellij, deleting .idea/ and any .iml files, then opening the project fresh.

I don't use that IDE but the error suggests that building/verification of other projects is going on by configured options. Do you really want that? I sure wouldn't

From comments and hints in here, I have decided to throw away IntelliJ, since it seems to maybe an IDE issue.
It was... Everything is honky dory in VScode...
I am going to explode and redownload IntelliJ I guess

I threw away all IDEs some time ago ;) VSCode is at least not written in Java afaik

Just raw dogging it? Respect

Do you have any idea where and why this JavaCUP thing came on your system?

Based on the screenshot, this is not a Maven dependency. Try closing the Project and removing the ".idea" folder from its' directory then re-import it by double-clicking its' pom.xml. If that does not help try removing IDEA's System Directory (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory)

I see that you have javaCUP (that I don't know), so you have to check if its setup application added/changed the classpath variable in your global or private Windows environment.
That maybe the reason why you could see the jar along the IntellJ jars.

That's not really an answer, so should be posted as a comment

Why not!? I told how to inspect the environment and remove the dependency if present.

Because at this point it's speculative, plus there's absolutely no evidence that it's anything directly to do with the classpath
